# How to call webview2 fixed version from Tauri?

Tags: rust, webview2, tauri

Is it possible to get Tauri to use webview2 fixed version? It looks like this functionality was under consideration via the Tauri bundler config (https://github.com/tauri-apps/tauri/issues/1378 )? The reason is we're considering moving away from .net/cefsharp to rust/tauri but the app is enterprise and we can't guarantee the existence of the webview2 runtime and we don't we want to be in the business of installing the runtime on customer PCs.  Currently the CefSharp binaries are included in the app.exe directory and deployed via msi (Wix). We're not too concerned about webview2 updates because the app only presents canned html included in the distro.

- I've tested (unsuccessfully) executing our Tauri app from within the root of the webview2 directory created by extracting the webview2 cab file.
- The Tauri app works fine when executed on a Windows PC with the webview2 runtime installed (as expected).

Comment: You can include the fixed version with your app and install it via msi. That way other programs on the user's pc won't know about WebView2.

Comment: Have you set the `BrowserExecutableFolder` in your code, so the code can find the fixed version?

Comment: I've successfully done what you describe with a .Net app but it doesn't work with a Tauri app which appears to require the webview2 runtime (not fixed) installed.  The problem is installing the webview2 runtime is for all users and adds a new running process "MS Edge Webview2" which is not something a lot of corp IT admins are crazy about just to support a single app.

Comment: BrowserExecutableFolder does not appear to be supported in tauri https://github.com/tauri-apps/tauri/issues/1378#issue-838519413